# Purpose of the different folders created by sphinx-quickstart

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am a newcomer to the sphinx world. Between the documentation and example I take from other github repository, I'm starting to get my configuration working. I would like now to clean up the doc folder, which is quickly building up, by sorting my different files in the correct folders. Which leads me to the question: what is the purpose of the different default folders created by sphinx? What is suppose to be placed inside?

```
_includes
_static
_templates
```

Comment: The purpose of `_templates` and `_static` is described here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-quickstart.html#cmdoption-sphinx-quickstart-dot.

Comment: I don't know anything about `_includes`.

Comment: @mzjn Yes, couldn't figure out much more either. I guess for now I'm using `_static` for images (it looks like the most common use case) and `_templates` for wel.. templates.  I removed `_includes` for now; as anyway it remained empty.